# Expected Search Time in Sequential Search Time

Tags: algorithm, search, big-o

I have a list of items arranged by decreasing order of probability. The distribution follows zipf's .i.e relative probability of key i is 1/i. In these case what would be big O expected search time for sequential search.

Answer (score 0):

The expected search time is the sum of:

the probability of the ith element multiplied with the work needed to find the ith element.

With relative probabilities, this is: 1 * 1 + 1/2 * 2 + 1/3 * 3 + ... = N

To get the result, you have to normalize it, that is, you have to divide this with the sum of relative probabilities: 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ..., which is the Nth harmonic number, approximately log N.

So the answer is O(N / log N).